# Do scouting bees get to pass their genes to offspring?

Tags: natural-selection

Let's say the food-scouting behavior of scouting bees are enhanced when some particular alleles are expressed. By natural selection, the allele frequency for that "good" allele should increase because more of the scouting bees with that allele get to pass the allele to offspring generations, as more of them survive in the ecosystem.

But considering that only male bees get to produce offspring with the queen bee, do scouting bees (I assume to be females) ever get a chance to pass their genes to future generations? Or are they males? If they are males, do they get to produce offspring?

Comment: I think this question has a fundamental problem: You are using the term `their genes` as in regular sexual selection. In highly social collectives such as bees you better not think of the individual, but see the whole collective as one big evolving complex. The worker bee cannot reproduce itself, but here this is not a severe evolutionary problem. By raising offspring it will help the genes of her hive (and therefore also her genes to some extend) to prosper.